# Is it possible to detect from which node a transaction was issued?

Tags: transaction, node

Is it possible to detect from which node a transaction was issued?

When my node receive many spam transactions for example, can I be sure that my neighbor issue them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information about the IP address of the origin of each transaction is recorded by each IRI node in the local database. That is the IP that sent it to that node and does not mean it is the actual original IP address within the network.

If a cluster of nodes was formed, and the neighbor states also recorded and kept in sync, with some luck someone could approximate the original IP.

Honey pots could also be setup that offer tips that are marked. That is another way the origin could be narrowed down.

In practicality, the IP is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

In a transaction there is no field referring to the node which issued it and I don't think you're able to reconstruct the history of a transaction.

I think you cannot know in any way where a transaction comes from (but I'm not sure, I never tried anything like this)

Comment: Thanks for the info, as a light node user I didn't know this! So this means that a full node stores more than the transaction in its database. What else is stored?